# Inconsistent External Command Output

Tags: perl, md5

The terminal transcript speaks for itself:

```
iMac:~$ echo -n a | md5
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
iMac:~$ perl -e 'system "echo -n a | md5"'
c3392e9373ccca33629d82b17699420f
```

Note that the  MD5 hash of `a` is  0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661, the first
result. Why does it turns out to  be different when the same command is called
by perl?

---

By the way, perl is *perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level*. And the system: Mac OS 10.8, Darwin 12.0

Comment: Odd, both return `0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661` on both linux and freebsd for me

Comment: Oh man, that is _really_ odd, and complicates it even more. Maybe a bug?

Comment: Very strange, I also just confirmed that I too get your results on mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in the `/bin/sh` shell on mac, `echo -n` doesn't not print out the newline like it does in `/bin/bash`. You can see this if you drop into `/bin/sh` and run `echo -n a`, your output should look like this:

```
sh-3.2$ echo -n a
-n a
```

so you're literally getting `-n a` instead of the desired `a`. As perl system runs `/bin/sh` to evaluate your command, `-n a` is being passed into md5 instead of your desired `a`

Answer (score 2):

The specific question has already been answered, but I want to point out that od is useful to help understand exactly what any command outputs or file contains. This is useful especially to show otherwise non-printing characters.

```
$ echo -n a | od -tc
0000000    a                                                            
0000001

$ perl -e 'system "echo -n a | od -tc";'
0000000    -   n       a  \n                                            
0000005
```